# Calling fftR4() in c from assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, makefile, stm32

I am trying to get an ASM FFT implementation from www.embeddedsignals.com to work. But running make always gives the error:

```
undefined reference to fftR4(short*, short*, int)
```

at the top of the ASM I have

```
.syntax unified
.thumb
.global fftR4  
.type   fftR4, %function
```

and then there are some #define's that associate the C functions arguments with registers followed by some macros that the fftR4 function uses. After that, fftR4 is called

```
    .thumb_func
fftR4:   stmfd   sp!, {r4-r11, lr}
    mov     tmp0, #0            // bit reversed counter
    mov     tmp1, #0
    .word 0xF3A2FA92  //rbit R3,R2  //RBIT R,N
lsl     R,#3
```

And my C code is as follows:

```
void fftR4(short *y, short *x, int N);

short x[512]; 
short y[512]; 
int i;

void loop()
{
    for (i=0;i<512;i++) x[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<512;i=i+8)
    { x[i+0]=16384; x[i+2]=16384;   x[i+4]=-16384;  x[i+6]=-16384;}

    fftR4(y, x, 256);

    SerialUSB.println(y[128]);
    SerialUSB.println(y[129]);
    SerialUSB.println(y[384]);
    SerialUSB.println(y[385]);

    // expected results:
    //y[128]is 8191; y[129] is -8190   y[384]is 8191; y[385]is 8191 
    //z[2n] is 64 64 -64 -64 ..  z[2n+1] is 0    all +- 1 (noise)
    while(1);
}
```

What needs to be done to make fftR4 recognizable to the C file?

Comment: Is your error coming from the linker or the compiler? If it's the linker, check the command line to ensure all object files are included on it. Then use 'nm' to inspect the object file you think should contain the `fftR4` function to check that it actually does.

Comment: thank you so much. looking into the nm command did the trick. yes, the function names in the oject file were being 'mangled' because it was c++. alittle bit of 
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" 
#endif 

did the trick.
thank you x1000